# How can I share props in ReasonReact?

Tags: reason, reason-react

### Summary

Suppose I have a `reducerComponent`

```
<TodoList />
```

that uses `statelessComponent`

```
<TodoItem todo />
```

Here `todo` is a record type called `todoItem`.

```
type todoItem = {
  text: string,
  isDone: bool,
};
```

But, I can't share `todoItem` type.

- If I define the type in `TodoList.re` 
  `TodoItem` will complain.
- If I define the type in `TodoItem.re`
  `TodoList` will complain.

### Sources

Here is my `TodoList.re`

```
/** TodoList.re */

// ↓ I defined `todoItem` type
type todoItem = {
  text: string,
  isDone: bool,
};

// state depends on `todoItem` type ↓
type state = {todoList: list(todoItem)};

let component = ReasonReact.reducerComponent("TodoList");

let make = _children => {
  ...component,
  initialState: () => {todoList: []},
  reducer: (action, state) => ...,
  render: self =>
    <div> {List.map(todo => <TodoItem todo />, self.state.todoList)} </div>,
};
```

And `TodoItem.re`

```
/** TodoItem.re */

let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("TodoItem")

let make  = (~todo, _children) => {
    ...component,
    render: (_self) => {
        // ↓ I'm getting an error here
        <p>(ReasonReact.string(todo.text))</p>
    }
}
```

#### Error message

```
[1/2] Building ...em-ReactTemplate.cmj

  We've found a bug for you!
  /Users/kkweon/temp/my-react-app/src/components/TodoItem.re 6:37-40

  4 │     ...component,
  5 │     render: (_self) => {
  6 │         <p>(ReasonReact.string(todo.text))</p>
  7 │     }
  8 │ }

  The record field text can't be found.

  If it's defined in another module or file, bring it into scope by:
  - Annotating it with said module name: let baby = {MyModule.age: 3}
  - Or specifying its type: let baby: MyModule.person = {age: 3}

>>>> Finish compiling(exit: 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Each Reason file is a module.

So, after defining

```
type todoItem = {
  text: string,
  isDone: bool,
};
```

in `TodoItem.re`

I can call it as

```
type state = {todoList: list(TodoItem.todoItem)};
```

Comment: you can create a easier to read file call `Item_t.re` and `type t ={text:...}` this way you know that you can call a list of Item type, list(Item_t.t) and you can have other methods inside the Item_t file, like `let listOfItems=list(t)`, `let item2 = (t, t)` etc...